# Что можно удалить с загрузочного сектора дискеты freedos 1.2, чтобы вставить туда свой ассемблерный код

Tags: ассемблер

Имеется файл загрузочной дискеты freedos 1.2. Необходимо в первые 512 байт, то есть в загрузочный сектор, вставить свой небольшой код, который выполнится перед загрузкой freedos.
Проблема в том, что там все занято, непонятно, что можно убрать из него

Comment: Freedos, дискета… мы точно в 2022 году?

Comment: Ничего оттуда убрать нельзя, там свободных байтов кот наплакал. Впрочем, если переместить этот сектор в какое-то определённое местоположение и на его место положить нужный код (таблицы дисковой структуры не трогать!), который после отработки грузит на своё место исходный бутсектор и передаёт ему управление (эдакий сплайсинг - собсно так работают почти все досовые бут-вирусы) - то почему бы и нет... Рекомендую использовать последний сектор дискеты, пометив в файловой системе его кластер как зарезервированный или как бэд.

Comment: Хм, подмену сектора уже реализовывал, вариант рабочий. Но сейчас задача как раз в том, чтобы именно в оригинальный вставить. А может есть дискета, на которой в загрузочном секторе где-нибудь байт 80-120 свободных?